# how to find snippets when building a new WordPress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I had gone through the current default theme (twentytwelve maybe) and looked through the code to find the core functions that make the theme work in files like index, page, single etc.

Is there a more efficient/cleaner way to find the snippets for each major theme file when starting to make a new theme? If not, how do you all do it? Do you do what I did and then reuse that template ?

Comment: http://underscores.me/

Comment: I looked around at tutorials and pieced together a template that worked for me. http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-create-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch--net-706

Comment: Another good way to learn how to write core loops and such is to check out https://generatewp.com/ or look over this tutorial that explains http://code.tutsplus.com/series/mastering-wp_query--cms-818

Comment: Thanks. The _s theme looks very useful and that snippet generator seems like it could save a ton of hassle.

Comment: There is no definite answer for this, as it's primarily opinion based. There are many different ways to develop Wordpress themes and each developer has their own method. I would say that what you've been doing is the best way to approach it, just look at other popular themes built by respected developers and see how they did it.

Comment: nearly all the templates will be based on the loop, so you only need 2 snippets, one for a single post, and then one for posts lists. Develop your own base off this, also google wp templates hierarchy. At least then you will understand it all in depth :)